Restricting response in the new Google Places API (New)
I am using the "Place autocomplete" feature of the new Google Places API. My requirement is that I want to restrict my response to a specific country. In the old Google Places API It was possible to use it like this
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json
?input=Karn
&key=<key>
&type=(regions)
&components=country:in

But when it comes to the new version, I couldn't find it anywhere in the document on how to restrict responses to a specific country.
Also, I couldn't find anywhere on how I can pass multiple values to the key "includedPrimaryTypes"
https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:autocomplete
?key =<key>
&fields=suggestions.placePrediction.structuredFormat.mainText.text
&input=Karn
&includedPrimaryTypes=(regions)


Yes , as I mentinoed using the old version of google places API , I could solve my requirement. I am having trouble with the new version.

Sorry, I had the wrong links.  Docs show "includedRegionCodes": ["de", "fr"] as an example for limiting by country. I would assume that's also the syntax for passing multiple values to "includedPrimaryTypes"

Also, "Pass all parameters in the JSON request body or in headers as part of the POST request" according to the docs.

Yeah, about that. I made it work by passing it as a query parameter. The new API will work with both JSON and Request params.
Thanks for the help.
